# Does Python's warnings.simplefilter() check the message?

Tags: python, warnings

How can I get a Python warning to be displayed the first time it is issued at some location and not again?

The [`default` action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter) is supposed to only show the first warning at a particular line in a module, and [`warnings.simplefilter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter) is supposed to work regardless of the warning's message, however it appears to only work for warnings with the same message string. Here is a MWE using Python 3.7:

```py
>>> import warnings
>>> class MyWarning(Warning): pass
... 
>>> warnings.simplefilter('default', MyWarning)
>>> for i in range(3):
...     warnings.warn(str(i), MyWarning)  # unique message each time
...     warnings.warn('foo', MyWarning)   # same message each time
... 
__main__:2: MyWarning: 0
__main__:3: MyWarning: foo
__main__:2: MyWarning: 1
__main__:2: MyWarning: 2
```

Even if I use the `module` or `once` actions (which I do not want, anyway), it still shows those with unique messages each time. Furthermore, even if I use the more explicit [`warnings.filterwarnings()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings) with a message that should match anything, it still shows them each time:

```py
warnings.filterwarnings('default', r'.*', MyWarning)
```

Am I missing something? Or maybe the documentation is inaccurate [again](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201810/why_warnings_is_mysterious.html)?

Comment: It does say that the filter "always matches any message", so any unique message will always be matched at least once.  What you want is a filter specific to a once per line number, which is not implemented by default.

Comment: So the filters only determine which action will be used; whether the warning will actually be displayed depends on a secondary test for message contents?

Comment: It's not so much secondary when the matching is defined to be done against a registry of recorded warnings using a [3-tuple (key, category, lineno)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.5/Lib/warnings.py#L362) as they key (CPython typically would do this in [`_warnings.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.5/Python/_warnings.c#L530))

Comment: By 'secondary' I mean that the filters do not directly determine whether or not a warning is shown. A matching filter determines the action which is then applied to the specific warning, including its message. At least, that's how I now understand it. The registry just seems to be a shortcut to avoid the expensive filter check; if the specific warning is in the registry it should not be shown.

Comment: Yes, that is correct - a message that is matched (via the 3-tuple key) against the registry (basically a `dict`) will then have the filter applied (for logging, showing, recording, omitting, or otherwise), and if no match it will be added to the registry.